# Profiler for IAR EW for ARM

Tags: c++, arm, profiler, iar

I am trying to get the profiler plug-in for IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM to work. I have set everything in the documentation but when I fire up C-Spy and start the plug-in I get errors. I tried to different emulators and each gave a different error:

**Segger SAM-ICE JTAG Emulator** - The following appears in the debug log:

```
Thu May 27 12:43:04 2010: Profiler: No cycle counter could be found. Profiler will only count function calls. 
Thu May 27 12:43:04 2010: Failed to set breakpoint at 0x001411F2 
Thu May 27 12:43:04 2010: Profiler: Could not set enough breakpoints.
```

**J-Link Pro Emulator** - A pop-up window appears with the following:

```
No More Breakpoints Available
Available breakpoints: 2048
```

It appears that the emulators do not support the plug-in. Has anyone successfully used this plug-in? If so with which emulator?

Does anyone know of a alternative method or solution that I could use (i.e. in code)? It would preferably meet the following conditions:

- Be as memory efficient as possible because I have very little RAM in the application left.
- Be able to play with an RTOS nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a better way. Use the GDB Server and [use this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).